# how can load all dumped appended dict in python pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

i have solved a exercise for pickle and i dump a dict first with pickle and then need to dump another dict and append it to previous dump file this work but when i want to load file and get two dict together just get back the first dumped dict how can solve this problem?

```
with open('test.ts', 'ab') as f:
    pickle.dump({'first': 1}, f)

with open('test.ts', 'ab') as f:
    pickle.dump({'second': 2}, f)

with open('test.ts', 'rb') as f:
    t = pickle.load(f)

>>>print(t)

>>>{'first': 1} #need to get dictionaries like this {'first': 1}{'second': 2}
```

Comment: Not really the answer to your question.  But can you dump `(dict1, dict2)` as a single item, and then `dict1, dict2 = pickle.load(f)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the file using `pickle.load` multiple times:

```
t1 = pickle.load(f)
t2 = pickle.load(f)
```